# CSS3 animations with keyframes

Tags: html, css, notepad++, css-animations

So I have been trying to solve this problem for over an hour. I use Notepad++ as my code editor, and I have been trying to do a css3 animation, but it won't work. Notepad++ will not recognize the "@" in "@-webkit-keyframes." It remains black while the other text is highlighted blue. I have made new files countless times and nothing works. My code is below:

HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Animation</title>
        <link href="stylesheetani.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="change">
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

CSS:

```
    #change {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      border: 2px solid black;
      -webkit-animation: changeColor 8s infinite;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes changeColor {
      0% {background-color: blue;}
      25% {background-color: yellow;}
      50% {background-color: green;}
      75%{background-color: red;}
      100% {background-color: black;}
    }
```

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Notepad++ does not run your code, it is simply attempting to highlight your syntax. Just because the ``@-webkit-keyframes`` is not the correct color does not mean your code is incorrect, it just means that Notepad++ does not support syntax highlighting for that particular CSS selector.

Comment: If I place the text in Notepad++ it gets highlighted normally. Maybe you're not using the latest version. However, the code should work. (also, you're missing a space after 75%, but that shouldn't matter)

Comment: I'm using Chrome. I just tried it again and it worked. I have no idea what went wrong, but thanks for your help!

Comment: I would suggest you to use the dev tools of a modern browser to edit CSS. Wich one to use is up to you , but any one of them is a better way of working than using an external tool (IMHO)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the other vendor prefixes, but other than that your code should work properly, as demonstrated below:

```css
#change {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  -webkit-animation: changeColor 8s infinite;
  -moz-animation: changeColor 8s infinite;
  animation: changeColor 8s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes changeColor {
  0% {background-color: blue;}
  20% {background-color: yellow;}
  40% {background-color: green;}
  60% {background-color: red;}
  80% {background-color: black;}
  100% {background-color: blue;}
}

@-moz-keyframes changeColor {
  0% {background-color: blue;}
  20% {background-color: yellow;}
  40% {background-color: green;}
  60% {background-color: red;}
  80% {background-color: black;}
  100% {background-color: blue;}
}

@keyframes changeColor {
  0% {background-color: blue;}
  20% {background-color: yellow;}
  40% {background-color: green;}
  60% {background-color: red;}
  80% {background-color: black;}
  100% {background-color: blue;}
}
```

```html
<div id="change"></div>
```

As a side note, I changed the percentages and added one more keyframe to smoothly transition back to blue.

Comment: FYI Firefox has used unprefixed animations for quite some time now.

Comment: @TylerH FYI, backwards compatibility is a thing :)

Comment: Thank you! It worked now. I have no idea what was wrong

Comment: @Snoop2001 as I said, nothing was wrong. The lack of syntax highlighting did not mean your code was incorrect.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Yes, but you don't see people including polyfills for IE8 in answers today unless that's an explicit requirement. Firefox has supported un-prefixed animations since mid-2012.

Comment: @TylerH IE8 is not a modern browser. Firefox is. Not everyone updates their browsers. It's helpful to at least point out that ``-webkit-`` is not the only vendor prefix that exists.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Firefox *37* is a modern browser, definitely. Firefox 5 through 15, not nearly as much.

Comment: @TylerH I'm leaving the prefix in there. If you feel that doing so somehow makes this answer incorrect then write your own answer.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts My comment wasn't about correcting an error in your answer, but rather about providing important additional information.